# Problema al utilizar pnputil desde Python

Tags: python-3.x

Necesito deshabilitar y habilitar un puerto USB de mi computadora al momento de iniciar una app que estoy programando. Para eso estoy usando los comandos:

**pnputil /disable-device "USB\VID_1A86&PID_7523\5&2DFFFC1D&0&2"**

**pnputil /enable-device "USB\VID_1A86&PID_7523\5&2DFFFC1D&0&2"**

desde la terminal y funcionan perfecto. El problema viene cuando intento implementarlo en un script de Python:

```
import subprocess


portname = '"USB\VID_1A86&PID_7523\5&2DFFFC1D&0&2"'


# Disable the device
subprocess.run(['pnputil', '/disable-device', portname] )

# Enable the device
subprocess.run(['pnputil', '/enable-device', portname] )
```

La terminal me arroja:

> Utilidad PnP de Microsoft
>
> No se pudo deshabilitar el dispositivo:
> "USB\VID_1A86&PID_7523♣&2DFFFC1D&0&2" El nombre de instancia del
> dispositivo no es válido.
>
> Utilidad PnP de Microsoft
>
> No se pudo habilitar el dispositivo:
> "USB\VID_1A86&PID_7523♣&2DFFFC1D&0&2" El nombre de instancia del
> dispositivo no es válido.

Nótese por favor que tanto en el codigo, cómo en la terminal el nombre del dispositivo esta entre comillas dobles, por lo que no tiene sentido que no lo reconozca. He prguntado a la IA y me ha dado variantes del código:

```
import subprocess
import shlex

portname = '"USB\VID_1A86&PID_7523\5&2DFFFC1D&0&2"'

# Split the command line into arguments
args = shlex.split(portname)

# Disable the device
subprocess.run(['pnputil', '/disable-device'] + args)

# Enable the device
subprocess.run(['pnputil', '/enable-device'] + args)
```

Pero me siguen dando el mismo resultado. Por favor si alguien puede ayudarme se lo agradecería.

Edit: EL error me dice que el Id de la instancia no es válido. Anexo la descripción del dispositivo pnputil:

**Id. de instancia:                USB\VID_1A86&PID_7523\5&2dfffc1d&0&2**

**Descripción del dispositivo:         USB-SERIAL CH340 (COM4)**

**Nombre de clase:                 Ports**

**GUID de clase:                 {4d36e978-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}**

**Nombre del fabricante:          wch.cn**

**Estado:                     Iniciado**

Nombre del controlador:          oem6.inf

Comment: ♣ Prueba escapando las barras invertidas `portname = '"USB\\VID_1A86&PID_7523\\5&2DFFFC1D&0&2"'` o con  `portname = r'"USB\VID_1A86&PID_7523\5&2DFFFC1D&0&2"'`

Comment: hola @FJSevilla lo acabo de intentar de ambas formas y pasó algo interesante,  ya he dicho que antes la terminal me decía: No se pudo deshabilitar el dispositivo: **"USB\VID_1A86&PID_7523♣&2DFFFC1D&0&2" El nombre de instancia del dispositivo no es válido.** Sin embargo, al intentar ambas de tus opciones, la terminal me arrojó: **No se pudo habilitar el dispositivo:  "USB\VID_1A86&PID_7523\5&2DFFFC1D&0&2"
La instancia del dispositivo no existe en el árbol de hardware.** Lo que me indica que el nombre que usé en el código si existe, pero no es valido